# Question on functional design

Tags: design

Functional architectures combined with solution charts are one way of designing a system.

My question is, if a product is a complex heirarchy of components (for example a potatoe harvesting machine), are there usually multiple functional architectures for each component or one large functional architecture for the entire system?

Comment: that depends on your budget for R&D

Comment: Generally 2 components. a)tractor b) potato harvesting machine like a Double L 973

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to work with a smaller system at once. Ideally, for a designer, to work with modules, that hide the internal complexity.

Only case I know where extreme level of details at one level that you imagine is happening is a plane design. Even then electronics is separate.

In absolute majority of cases where you dont need such extreme safety requirements, you just design a module, loosely define it outer boundary, torque, work hours, weight, and thats about it. And then you combine modules to get a machine you want. Make sure modules dont intersect each other physically, center of mass is ok for a moving machine, power is sufficient, repair intervals are at least a bit aligned, and call it a day.

Another example where somewhat full details are accessible at once is building information modelling. Where you can access all the data from concrete type to ventilation throughput.

In all cases electronics, optics, bio-stuff, and other information-heavy system are excluded from the big model. And modeled separately. Because of their extreme use of resources.